# tkinter - how to open multiple filedialogs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

in python's default editor, IDLE, it is possible to have multiple 'Open' dialogs opened at the same time.

I'm looking at their source, but I can't find where I can have this behavior replicated. from their `IOBinding.py`'s :

```
from tkinter import filedialog as TkFileDialog
...

class IOBinding:
    ...
    def askopenfile(self):
        dir, base = self.defaultfilename("open")
        if not self.opendialog:
            self.opendialog = tkFileDialog.Open(master=self.text,
                                                filetypes=self.filetypes)
        filename = self.opendialog.show(initialdir=dir, initialfile=base)
        return filename
```

so they do use tkinter's built-in filedialog module, but I can't find way to have some 'modeless' dialogs. I can have dialogs opened by two codes, which are basically same:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as tkFileDialog

file_name = tkFileDialog.Open( ... ).show()
file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

but they blocks whole application - users cannot switch windows or issue new command until they close the dialog. also, I can't call these dialog functions from different thread - that will kill whole my Tk app. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`filedialog` have `parent` option. You can change it to hidden window to prevent blocking the root window:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as tkFileDialog
from tkinter import *

def ask_open():
    p = hidden if attach_to_hidden.get() else root
    tkFileDialog.Open(parent=p).show()

root = Tk()
hidden = Toplevel()
hidden.withdraw()

attach_to_hidden = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text='Attach to hidden window', variable=attach_to_hidden).pack()
Button(root, text='Open', command=ask_open).pack()

root.mainloop()
```